# What is the path for application.properties (or similar file) in docker container?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am dockerizing springboot application(with PostgreSQL). I want to overwrite application.properties in docker container with my own application.properties.
My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  API:
    image: 'api-docker.jar'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - PostgreSQL
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - C:/path/to/my/application.properties:/path/of/application.properties/in/container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
```

I am doing this to overwrite the application.properties in container with my application.properties file so that the data gets stored in localhost

I tried the path /opt/application.properties but it didn't work.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is your question about the environment variables you use or about the `application.proprties`  volume you're using? If it's the latter, then be aware that you mapped the volume on the postgres-container and not on your API-container.

Comment: @g00glen00b It's not about environments variables. I want to map my application.properties on the docker container's application.properties. I want to store the data in my system(postgresql database) rather then storing it in the docker and for that I want to know where that file is stored in the docker. 
We know postgresql data is stored in /var/lib/postgresql/data in docker container. Where will the configuration for that (application.properties) be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes across the same problem, here is the solution.
I am trying to use my localhost database instead of in-memory database(storing it in container). This is my docker-compose.yml configuration

```
version: '2'
services:
  API:
    image: 'api-docker.jar' #(your jar file name)
    volumes:
      - path/to/new/application.properties:/config/env   
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

You need to provide a new application.properties file which contains the configuration for storing the data into your local database(could be the copy of your actual application.properties). This file needs to be overwritten in the config file of the container and the path to that is /config/env (which is mentioned in the yml file)

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions:

**1) First solution**

Create application.properties with env variable

```
mycustomproperties1: ${MY_CUSTOM_ENV1}
mycustomproperties2: ${MY_CUSTOM_ENV2}
```

I advise you to create different application.properties (application-test,application-prod, etc...)

**2) Another solution**

Create docker file:

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
RUN apt install wget -y
RUN apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates wget dirmngr gnupg software-properties-common -y
RUN wget -qO - https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/api/gpg/key/public | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository --yes https://adoptopenjdk.jfrog.io/adoptopenjdk/deb/
RUN apt update
RUN apt install adoptopenjdk-8-hotspot -y

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.config.location="file:///config/application.properties","/app.jar"]
```

or add env variable in docker compose

```
SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///config/application.properties
```

modify docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
API:
  image: 'api-docker.jar'
  ports:
  - "8080:8080"
  depends_on:
  - PostgreSQL
  environment:
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://PostgreSQL:5432/postgres
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
  - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
  - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
  - SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///config/application.properties
  volumes:
  - C:/path/to/my/application.properties:/config/application.properties
```

Comment: There are two application.properties, one in spring boot application (under resources) and the other one in a different folder. The application.properties in the different location is the one I have mentioned under volumes. I have mentioned the postgresql configuration in it so that it can override the application.properties in docker image.
Like there is /var/lib/postgresql/data is there any  path for application.properties?

Comment: Create two volume one for db /var/lib/postgresql/data and one for application.properties ->  /opt/config/application.properties create config folder, if docker image not start.

Comment: I did as you told. Now my docker-compose.yml looks like this:
`
PostgreSQL:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - C:/path/to/some/randon/folder/to_store_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - C:/path/to/external/application.properties:/opt/config/application.properties
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
`
I am able to add the data to the database but it is not reflected in the my physical machine database.